# State is not being updated after calling API within useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am working with a simple React app and am trying to render a page which is pulling data from a separate Flask REST API. This should happen during the first time the page is being rendered.

For context, it is supposed to be the summary / result page at the end of a quiz assessment.

Currently, I am not making any axios requests to the service but simply returning a placeholder object as follows:

```
const fetchResult = async () => {
    const body = {
        data: data,
        quizData: quizData
    };

    //const response = await axios.post(api, body);

    const res = {
        summary: {
            name: "someone",
            estimator: "eap",
            ability: "1.75643",
            total_questions: "15",
            total_correct: "10"
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

From what I have gathered thus far, my impression is that applying the useEffect() hook will be the correct method to ensure that my page renders properly with all the data in place. This is what I have for now:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [result, setResult] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    const res = fetchResult()
    setResult(res)
    console.log(result) // this prints null
    setLoading(false)
}, [])
```

However, there is clearly something wrong since I always encounter a problem where my 'result' state is null. Specific error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

Just in case it's relevant, this is what my component is returning:

```
return (
    <>
        {loading && <Loader></Loader>}
        {!loading && result &&
            <Box sx={{
                marginTop: 10,
                display: 'flex',
                flexDirection: 'column',
                border: 'solid 1px grey',
                padding: '20px',
            }}>
                <Grid container spacing={2}>
                    <Grid item md={12}>
                        <Typography variant="h4">Summary of Quiz</Typography>
                    </Grid>
                    {Object.entries(result.summary).map( (k, v) => 
                    <>
                        <Grid item md={6}>
                            <Typography>{k}</Typography>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item md={6}>
                            <Typography>{v}</Typography>
                        </Grid>
                    </>
                    )}
                </Grid>
            </Box>
        }
    </>
);
```

I have tried modifying the second argument of the useEffect() function to [result] as well to no avail. I am aware that this appears to be a commonly raised issue here, but I just can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: Modified jsx portion on mapping object key -> value. However, main issue still stems from my state not being updated at the end of useEffect().

Comment: result.summary must be array, but it looks like an object.

Comment: you are right! I have modified that portion; however my state is still null at the end of useEffect and now the error is "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Answer (score 2):

As @SuleymanSah mentions, you are iterating over an object with an array function. Hence your TypeError. You need to convert the object to an array to be able to iterate it with `map()` like so:

```
    Object.entries(result.summary).map((key,value) => ...
```

Comment: hi! thanks for pointing out the mistake. however, i am encountering a separate error "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object". i guess the original problem still remains, the state is not being updated within the useEffect hook.

Comment: fetchResult is returning a Promise. Thus, you need to handle it inside your useEffect: `const res = fetchResult().then(res => res)`

Comment: hi mike, appreciate your response. after some trial and error with your suggestion, i managed to get it to work by applying setResult() inside the resolution of the promise. fetchResult( (res) => setResult(res) ) thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Great to hear, @jun! Happy coding my dude.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the documentation of [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks) you will find

> **What does useEffect do?** By using this Hook, you tell React that your component needs to do something ***after render***.

Notice the ***after render*** part.

So in the first render the `result` will have the initial value you passed to `useState`, in your case `null`.

The other issue with your code is that you are using `.map` on the `result.summary` which is an object and not an array. You will have to change the way you store your data, or change the way you render it to match the schema.

So, after fixing the schema/structure of your data, you need to guard against a `null` value before trying to access its sub-properties.

Something like

```
result.summary && result.summary.map(...)
```

---

Or you could use newer features of the JS language, like the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```
result?.summary?.map(...)
```

---

Lastly, for when your fetch is actually doing a `fetch` try

```
useEffect(async () => {
    setLoading(true)
    const res = await fetchResult()
    setResult(res)
    console.log(result) // this prints null
    setLoading(false)
}, [])
```

So that you wait until the fetch is completed before using the `setResult`

Comment: hi Gabriele, thank you for your response. applying the check for result.summary also helped to resolve my problem which had multiple issues in the beginning :)